# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN on Google App Engine website

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

For unknown reasons my website on Google App Engine is suddenly not loading anymore on multiple devices and in different browsers. It gives a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error. I tried restarting the DNS service, changing DNS to Google's, and restarting devices. Nothing helped so far. All other websites load without issues. What could be causing this?

Comment: http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/

Comment: Thx. Down for everyone according to this website. So I have to check my domain settings?

Comment: Oh, just wanted to login to WhoIs domain registration and I get the same error. So guess those guys are having an issue...

Comment: I guess so. My GAE site (on a custom domain) is running

Comment: Yes, the .appspot.com version of my page works without problems.

Comment: Voted to close, as it's just a specific issue for you, not a question that can be answered. Good luck getting it sorted.

Comment: Ok sure. Thanks. Should I close this myself by adding an answer or is that an admin thing?

Comment: you can just delete it or adding your own answer is also acceptable :)

Comment: downforeveryoneorjustme.com  return : It's not just you! google.com is down.
_ This website is not working properly _ @PaulCollingwood

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are some issues at my domain provider. Their website is giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent weeks fighting with this problem on 2 different unrelated computers, even unable to ping Yahoo.com and having variety of connectivity issues in web browsers, including "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN" and "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED".
I've tried various ipconfig commands, restarting DNS client service, "netsh winsock reset", and other solutions found on the internet.

Finally I realized the only common thing on both my computers was Malwarebytes. After closing/exiting Malwarebytes the problem was solved.
I am now able to ping and access every website.
The solution, again, at least in my case: close Malwarebytes

I just contacted Malwarebytes support but in the meantime wanted to provide the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Run following command from cmd

```
ipconfig /release

ipconfig /all

ipconfig /flushdns

ipconfig /renew

netsh int ip set dns

netsh winsock reset ###( Need to run in administrator mode)
```

If not successful then

Restart your PC